# is it possible to navigate using j, k command in vscode source action menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When a popup like a video below is opened through this source action in the vscode editor, how do I navigate the menu using the j and k keys?

image vscode editor

[image: 1]

---

temporary solution

I ended up solving this problem with a better touch tool or a karabiner keymapping tool. If you set it like the image below, you can navigate with ctrl + j,k keys. Of course, there are also side effects. You cannot use ctrl + j,k with the vim command. But since I don't use that command, this was enough to solve my problem.

[keymapping image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBhAu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in v1.71 these command id's will be changing, see [Align new code action widget command names with](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159348#issue-1352750155):

> We should try to align these command names with that ones that already
> exist for the suggestion widget
>
> `onEnterSelectCodeAction` -> `acceptSelectedCodeAction`
> (acceptSelectedSuggestion)
>
> `focusNextCodeAction` -> `selectNextCodeAction`
> (`selectNextSuggestion`)
>
> `focusPreviousCodeAction` -> `selectPrevCodeAction`
> (`selectPrevSuggestion`)

---

Coming to vscode v1.70 are some commands for navigating the code actions menu (or quickfix menu - previous answer covers both).

[image: navigate quickfix menu]

Sample keybindings:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+k",
  "command": "focusNextCodeAction",      // in v1.70
  // "command": "selectNextCodeAction"   // in v1.71
  "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
},
{
  "key": "down",
  "command": "-focusNextCodeAction",       // in v1.70
  // "command": "-selectNextCodeAction",   // in v1.71
  "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+j",
  "command": "focusPreviousCodeAction",     // in v1.70
  //  "command": "selectPrevCodeAction",    // in v1.71
  "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+up",
  "command": "-focusPreviousCodeAction",     // in v1.70
  // "command": "selectPrevCodeAction",      // in v1.71
  "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
},
```

---

There [wasn't, see above] a built-in way to do that, see the github issue [Missing keybinding for navigation in Quick Fix contextual menu](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/55111).

There are a couple of workarounds mentioned in that issue, including the extension [Keyboard Quickfix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalsenn.keyboard-quickfix), made specifically for this issue.

Comment: you suggested : editor.action.quickfix 
I want: editor.action.sourceAction

The method you suggested is an option regarding quickfix behavior. What I want to do is a source action, and the two are completely different actions.

I ended up solving this problem with a better touch tool or a karabiner key mapping tool. If you set it like the below key mapping, you can navigate with ctrl + j,k keys. Of course, there are also side effects. You cannot use ctrl + j,k with the vim command. But since I don't use that command, this was enough to solve my problem.

^K -> up
^J -> down

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for Java

Comment: @Tinker Check out the modified answer - you can test it now in the Insiders Build and soon in Stable (August 2022).

Comment: @Mark: I just installed insider, had your keybindings, installed the extension, and still could not get it to work. When I press Ctrl+J, it goes to the very bottom of the quick fix menu (but pressing it again doesn't do anything). Ctrl+K doesn't do anything

Comment: I had that same behaviour once.  I reloaded vscode and didn't get it again.  The bindings above have nothing to do with that `Keyboard Quickfix` extension.

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157129